# VLOOKUP when criteria exists mutliple times in matrix

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A             B          C            D
1  Product A      500      Product A       500 
2  Product B      800      Product A       700
3  Product C      450      Product A       300
4  Product A      700      Product B       800
5  Product A      300      Product B       400
6  Product C      300      Product B       250
7  Product B      400      Product C       450
8  Product B      250      Product C       300
```

In **Column A** and **Column B** the sales of differnt products are listed. A product can appear several times in Column A because each sale of the product is displayed.

In **Column C** the different products are sorted from A-C.

In **Column D** I want to use a `VLOOKUP` to get the sales from **Column B** for each of the products.

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$8,2)
```

However, since the products appear several times in **Column A** the `VLOOKUP` gives me only back one of the values.

How do I have to change the `VLOOKUP` to get each sale of the same product?

Comment: The first question to answer here is how are you defining "same product?"  You need to have some way of matching two products of the same name from columns `A` and `C`.

Comment: With same product I mean that for example Product A appears three times, Product B as well and Product C two times. Therefore, you are right I need to have some way to match two products of the same name from Columns A and C.

Comment: You need to provide logic for, e.g., _which_ Product A value you want to be associated with which Product A appearing in the `B` column.  You haven't done this.

Comment: Well for example the logic for Product A should be: Go through Column A, find all products with name "Product A" and then get the values from them. Starting with the first value you find (in this case 500) and end it with the last value you find (in this case 300).

Comment: I don't know if your current data would be enough to handle using pure Excel functions.  In a SQL database, your query would not be possible.  It might be possible using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get desired result single `VLOOKUP` formula.
Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=C1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)-ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,1,1))+1),COUNTIF($C$1:C1,C1)))
```

Paste it into `D1` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to change it into array formula, then pull formula down.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

Insert one empty row above the data, then put this formula in column D (you can hide this column if you want to):

```
=MATCH(D2;INDIRECT("$A"& 2 + IF(D2=D1;E1;0) & ":$A$9");0)+IF(D2=D1;E1;0)
```

And this formula in column E:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9;E2)
```

MATCH works similar to VLOOKUP but instead of the actual value returns the index of the result. `INDIRECT("$A"& 2 + IF(D2=D1;E1;0) & ":$A$9")` alters the searchmatrix based on the previous index of the search value (e.g. the first "Product A" is found at index 1 therefore the second "Product A" only looks in A3:A9, the second "Product A" is at index 4 thus the third "Product A" looks in A6:A9).

The second formula just extracts the value based on the matrix in column B and the index in column D.